# storing a string letter by letter and printing it

Tags: c++, string, storage, reverse

Why won't this program print out "hello" in reverse? It works when I uncomment the line inside the loop. I wanna know the concept behind why the string value isn't getting stored. Thank you!

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void reverse(string str) {
        int length = str.length();
        int x = length, i = 0;
        string newString;

        while(x >= 0) {
                newString[i] = str[x-1];
                //cout << newString[i];
                x--;
                i++;
        }

        cout << newString;
}

int main() {
        reverse("hello");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Time to use a debugger.  It should help you figure out what's going on fairly quickly.

Comment: Take a look at reference page for the [] operator in C++. It acts as a getter, not setter http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator[]/

Comment: I'm afraid that's not exactly true, @Cole. `[]` returns a reference allowing it to perform double duty. Assuming the `string` isn't constant, that is.

Comment: Or construct a reversed string `string newString(str.rbegin(), str.rend());`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`newString` has a size of 0 (constructed with the default constructor), so writing past the end of it with `newString[i] =`... causes undefined behavior.  Use `.resize` to resize the string (make it big enough) before writing into it

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with the program.

For starters you should include the header `<string>`

```
#include <string>
```

because the program uses declarations from this header. It is not necessary that the header `<iostream>` includes the header `<string>`

It is much better to declare the function like

```
void reverse(const string &str);
```

Otherwise a copy of the original string used as argument is created each time when the function is called.

For the size type the class `std::string` defines its own unsigned integer type named `size_type`. It is better to use it or the type specifier `auto` instead of the type `int`.

After this declaration

```
string newString;
```

`newString` is empty. So you may not apply the subscript operator. You should either resize the string or reserve enough memory for the new added elements to the string.

Taking this into account the function can be defined the following way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void reverse( const string &str) {
        auto length = str.length();
        string newString;
        newString.reserve( length );

        for ( auto i = length; i-- != 0;  ) newString += str[i];

        cout << newString << endl;
}

int main() {
        reverse("hello");

        return 0;
}
```

Take into account that the function could be defined simpler based on the features of the class `std::string` itself. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void reverse( const string &str) {
        string newString( str.rbegin(), str.rend() );

        cout << newString << endl;
}

int main() {
        reverse("hello");

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: could you explain to me the reasoning behind using "const string &str" a little bit more please? Thank you.

Comment: @aashman There is used a reference to the original string that is neither copy of the original string is created while in your program a copy of the original string is created each time the function is called. This is resource consumed.